# insert multiple rows (one to many) based on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There are two tables Inspector(Parent) and InspectorOfficeAccess(Child), i need to give inspectors from country (73,74) to have access of offices (1,20,24,31,44).

There are many inspectors (over 100) in Inspector table with country 73 and 74. Is this possible to insert all inspectors with officeid in InspectorOfficeAccess table with one query?

second screen shot is for showing how the final result should look like. InspectorOfficeAcess table is empty.

Each inspector will be inserted 5 times with officesID (1,20,24,31,44) where inspector country IN (73,74)

[image]

**ADDED**

I have tried this so far

```
insert into InspectorOfficeAccess 
select i.inspectorid,o.Offices    from Inspectors i
cross join 
        (
        SELECT 1 AS Offices
        UNION 
        SELECT 20
        UNION 
        SELECT 24
        UNION 
        SELECT 31
        UNION
        SELECT 44 
        ) o
where i.CountryID IN (73,74)
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. What did you try so far?

Comment: may be cross all inspectors of country (73,74) with officeID(1,20,24,31,44) and use this in insert statement.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to pick Office Id's from other table then another way for doing this would be :

```
Insert into InspectorOfficeAccess
Select I.InspectorID,O.OfficeId
from  Inspector I 
Cross Join Office O
where I.CountryId in (73,74) and O.OfficeId in (1,20,24,31,44);
```

You can check [Demo here.](http://rextester.com/SROFKL69840)

Comment: very clean example :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Insert into InspectorOfficeAcess
Select InspectorOfficeAccessiD,i.InspectorID,oficeid
from  Inspector i 
cross apply(Select 1 union Select 20 union Select 24 union Select 31 union Select 44) d
    where countryid in (73,74)
```

Comment: second screen shot is for showing how the final result should look like. InspectorOfficeAcess table is empty.

Comment: second screen shot showing three columns; InspectorOfficeAccessiD, i.InspectorID, oficeid
InspectorOfficeAccessiD is IDENTITY columns so 
i.InspectorID, oficeid are required.

Comment: Each inspector will be inserted 5 times with officesID (1,20,24,31,44) where inspector country IN (73,74)

Comment: don't worry about InspectorOfficeAccessiD as its identity column

Answer (score 0):

This will work for in your case:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT InspectorID
      FROM Inspector
      WHERE countryid in (73,74)) Inspector
,(VALUES (1),(20),(24),(31),(44)) 
AS InspectorOfficeAcess(InspectorOfficeAcessID)
```